# bosun lookup using multiple tags

Tags: bosun

I want notifications to be selected depending on tags. So I am using lookup.

```
notification default {
    email = mailid-1
    next = default
    timeout = 1m
}

notification nondefault {
    email = mailid-2
    next = nondefault
    timeout = 1m
}

lookup notif {
  entry some_tag=value {
    mail = nondefault
  }
  entry some_tag=* {
    mail = default
  }
}
```

And in alert I am giving

> critNotification = lookup("notif", "email")

My question is it possible to use multiple tags in 
lookup(I am using some_tag=value) ?
eg. something like

```
lookup notif {
  entry some_tag=value,some_other_tag=value {
    mail = nondefault
  }
  entry some_tag=* {
    mail = default
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an example in the [documentation](http://bosun.org/configuration#lookup) (kind of hard to find):

```
lookup cpu {
    entry host=web-*,dc=eu {
        high = 0.5
    }
    entry host=sql-*,dc=us {
        high = 0.8
    }
    entry host=*,dc=us {
        high = 0.3
    }
    entry host=*,dc=* {
        high = 0.4
    }
}

alert cpu {
    crit = avg(q("avg:rate:os.cpu{host=*,dc=*}", "5m", "")) > lookup("cpu", "high")
}
```

Comment: ahh my bad, completely missed it. Thanks